# function() is not a function;

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, computed-properties, vue-chartjs

I want my function to update the data displayed by a vue chart js each time I click on a button but I get this error: "_vm.chartData is not a function".

I use computed properties as told in the guide but I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what.

here is my code :

```
<template>
  <div>
  <Bar
    :chart-options="chartOptions"
    :chart-data="chartData"
  />
  <button v-on:click="chartData()">
    Change Data
</button>
  </div>
  
  
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs/legacy'

import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
} from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: {
    Bar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      }
    }
  },
computed :{
  chartData() { 
        const updatedChartData = {
            labels: [
              'January',
              'February',
              
            ],
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [
                  this.getRandomInt(),
                  this.getRandomInt(),
                ]
              }
              ]
          };
        console.log(updatedChartData.datasets)
        return updatedChartData;
      },
  },
  methods:{
    
    getRandomInt() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1)) + 5
      }
  }
  
  
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vue, the template is already bound to the context, so you don't need `this` for variables and methods.

Try this (no pun intended):
*Note the new variable `chartDataValues`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Bar
      :chart-options="chartOptions"
      :chart-data="chartDataValues"
    />
    <button v-on:click="chartData">
      Change Data
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs/legacy'

import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
} from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: {
    Bar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      },
      chartDataValues: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    chartData() { 
      const updatedChartData = {
        labels: [ 'January', 'February' ],
        datasets: [{
          data: [ this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt(), ]
        }]
      };
      console.log(updatedChartData.datasets)
      this.chartDataValues = updatedChartData;
    },

    getRandomInt() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1)) + 5
    }
  }
  
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: I just noticed you put `chartData` in the `computed` methods, `computed` is only used for styling, if it's logic you need to pass the function to `methods: {}`

Comment: I already tried this way but I get "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "chartData". Expected Object, got Function"

Comment: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts

Comment: yes, that's because `<Bar :chart-options="chartOptions" :chart-data="chartData"/>` is passing `chartData` and `chartData` is a function. Please note that `@click` expects a function and you pass the result when you add `()` to the function, and you pass a function on `Bar` when you don't add `()` to the function

Comment: @Guts I updated the whole code, please use this as example on how Vue works

Comment: It's working ! Thank you very much I took over someone's project and I'm having trouble with the framework at the moment.